# Difference between jquery:colorbox and ajax:ModalPopupExtender

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, colorbox, modalpopupextender

**I know here i can't ask suggestions**, but i am not getting any clear idea from anywhere.

I am going to display one submit popup window in my asp.net web project. I am going to put full aspx page here. I am not that much expert in asp.net.

So i got confuse with these jquery:colorbox and  ajax:ModalPopupExtender. Can anyone help me to understand the difference between these two. Like **speed, responsive**. Or i understood both wrongly.

As per my understanding the colorbox mostly used to display images and navigate between images and slideshow the images. If my popup page has server methods then what will happen on colorbox?.

Anyone feel this questions is inappropriate, Plz Flag to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two similar plugins, but I recommend jQuery Colorbox.

I think its generally considered the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit is redundant.

The code is clunky and obtrusive. It was good back in 2007, but not now.

> As per my understanding the colorbox mostly used to display images and
>   navigate between images and slideshow the images. If my popup page has
>   server methods then what will happen on colorbox?.

The correct thing to do is handle this with an AJAX request which you can write yourself without the use of the AJAX Control Toolkit.